# Operações complexas com Python (pygame.math.Vector2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, tupla

Estou aprendendo Python e me deparei com uma expressão complexa que deriva de `pygame.Vector2`:

```
import pygame
x = pygame.math.Vector2(1,2)
b = x * 5 - (1, 2)
print(x)
print(b)
```

Resultado:

```
[1, 2]
[4, 8]
```

No caso acima, a mesma operação `x * 5` é executada para os valores `1` e `2` do `Vector2`, resuldando em (5, 10) respectivamente; e em seguida, ambos os resultados são subtraídos da tupla `(1, 2)`, resultando em [4, 8]

Entretanto se eu fizer atribuir uma tupla simples a x: `x = (1, 2)`, ao invés de `Vector2`, eu recebo o erro:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Minha dúvida é: **em que momentos no Python eu consigo realizar estas operações complexas?**

Comment: Não sei quais os tipos que cada coisa tem, mas digo já de avanço que tuplas são imutaveis, por isso qualquer atribuição a uma tupla irá gerar um erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os tipos Vector2 e Vector3 do Pygame são classes especializadas, que, entre outras coisas, redefinem o comportamento dos operadores aritméticos para fazer operações "vetoriais" - ou seja, no caso de multiplicação por escalar, multiplicar os dois componentes, e no caso de soma com outro objeto que seja uma sequência de mesmo comprimento, somar os elementos um a um, e gerar um novo objeto.

Em Python é bem fácil criar uma classe com uma ou mais dessas características. Apesar de elas serem desejáveis na maior parte dos programinhas de jogos ou outros para manipular imagens na tela, é algo considerado tão "se alguém quiser, vai lá e faz", que o Pygame não implementou isso por mais de 15 anos, e essas duas são uma adição recente ao código.

## Comportamento Padrão para Sequências

As tuplas, listas, arrays, as próprias strings de texto, bytes e bytearrays e possivelmente outros objetos definidos na linguagem ou biblioteca padrão do Python são o que chamamos de "sequência" (Sequence) - em vão respeitar o protocolo definido pelos métodos listados em na linah MutableSequence (ou Sequence, se forem imutáveis) aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html

Além disso, para os operadores aritméticos, essas sequências vão funcionar assim com os operadores:

- `+` Adição: concatena duas sequências. se as duas sequências forem do mesmo tipo, é criada uma nova sequência que é formada pelos elementos da primeira, seguidos dos elementos da segunda.
- `*` Multplicação: somente é definida para um número inteiro - ela concatena a sequência com ela mesma N vezes, onde "N" é o segundo operador. Nesse sentido, a multiplicação de sequências em Python funciona igual a definição matemática, em que "A * N" é equivalente a "A + A + ..." com N repetições da soma.

Os outros operadores (principalmente `-` e `/`, mas também `%`, `**` e outros), não são definidos para sequência.

## Vetores

Agora, num desenho de 2 ou 3 dimensões, se eu tenho uma distância representada pelo vetor (1, 1), e quero dobrar essa distância, não quero (1, 1, 1, 1) - e sim (2, 2).

(Tentei achar rapidinho um artigo introdutório sobre algebra vetorial em português aqui, mas acho que os matemáticos são todos sádicos (com a licença para a alfinetada) - todos os primeiros links da busca partem de uma versão abstrata de um vetor com N dimensões e daí só piora - vamos ficar sem a formalização então).

O fato é que em Python se eu quero que uma classe que eu defina possa suportar operações personalizadas com os operadores aritméticos, e mesmo com o operador de recuperar item `item[x]`  usado nas sequências, tudo o que eu preciso é criar um método como o nome "mágico" apropriado dentro da classe. Esses métodos,chamados de "magic", ou "dunder methods" se distinguem por sempre começarem e terminarem com dois underscore (`__`). Todo mundo que já aprendeu, ou mesmo usou sem entender bem, classes em Python já usou o método `__init__` - esse é o método mágico chamado para inicializar a instância. Os métodos `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__mul__` e `__div__`, por exemplo, são chamados cada vez que sua instância é usada em conjunto com um dos 4 operadores aritméticos - respectivametne `+ - * /` . O `__getitem__` permite a recuperação de itens  como acontece com listas, strings, tuplas e dicionários.

A documentação de **todos** os magic methods usados internamente pela linguagem estão no documento chamado "[data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)", mas simplesmente criar sua classe para especializar alguns desses operadores é bem simples.

(Alguns métodos com o mesmo tipo de nome, por exemplo `__getstate__` são usados por componentes padrão da biblioteca do Python, como o módulo  `pickle`. O comportamento dos mesmos não é considerado parte da linguagem em si, portanto eles não são citados no data model)

O Vector2 do Pygame tem mais algumas coisas legais - por exemplo, ele "sabe" se virar se o outro operador for outro tipo de sequência. Ele disponibiliza os valores tanto como itens de sequência (`v[0]`), como por nomes dos componentes (x e y, como em `v.x`), etc...

Mas uma classe facinha que saiba fazer adição e multiplicão  vetorial pode ser simplesmente:

```
class ListaSoma(list):
   def __add__(self, other):
       if len(self) != len(other): 
           raise ValueError("Só pode ser adicionada a sequências do mesmo tamanho")
       result = ListaSoma()
       for ele_self, ele_other in zip(self, other):
             result.append(ele_self + ele_other)
       return result
   def __mul__(self, other):
       result = ListaSoma()
       for element in self:
            result.append(element * other)
       return result
```

(Aqui eu uso o `zip` para pegar um elemento de cada vez da própria instância e da outra lista).

Todas as outras funcionalidades de uma lista de Python são preservadas para essa classe, por conta da herança - apenas a adição e multiplicação são alteradas:

```
In [53]: a = ListaSoma([10, 20, 30])

In [54]: a + range(3)
Out[54]: [10, 21, 32]

In [55]: a + range(100, 400, 100)
Out[55]: [110, 220, 330]

In [56]: a * 5
Out[56]: [50, 100, 150]
```